# How to calculate percentile score for each row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to calculate the speed rank of drivers by looking at his/her past 20 race. However, i need to get get current value and rolling values to function. Here what i did so far:

```
def set_rank(x, y):
    return stats.percentileofscore(x,y)
df['Rank'] = df['SpeedRank'].rolling(20).apply(lambda x: set_rank(x, df['SpeedRank']), raw=True)
```

The problem is `y` how can i send value of corresponding row to the function?

Comment: Can you add  some data and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. Here is the solution:

```
def set_rank(x):
    return stats.percentileofscore(x,x[-1])
df['Rank'] = df['SpeedRank'].rolling(20).apply(set_rank, raw=True)
```